# How to change div background color inside list element?

Tags: jquery, css

I am new to jQuery, I have a list with 7 items, each containing an image and a div. I'm trying to change the div background color from black to orange when the image is clicked using jQuery. with the first `<li>` element it works fine but the problem is after I click another image the previous div color remains as clicked.

The codeIi'm using where `.imageRecharge` is the image class and `radioID` is the div class. I'm using the `siblings()` method to change the other divs but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.imageRecharge').click(function () {
         $(this).parent().find('.radioID').css({ 'backgroundColor': '#FF6600', 'color': 'black' })
         $(this).parents().find(' .radioID').siblings().css({ 'backgroundColor': 'black', 'color': '#FF6600' });
    });
});
```

Comment: Within the click function, reset the background color of all elements to the default before changing the background color of the currently clicked element. Also your CSS is not right, it should be `background-color`, not `backgroundColor`. If you post your HTML I'll make a Fiddle to show you.

Comment: Could you add a snippet of the html you got?

Comment: Please provide JSfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish:
http://jsfiddle.net/1e27hkxa/1/

JQuery:

```
$('ul').on('click', '.imageRecharge', function() {
    $(this).parents().find('.radioID').css('background', 'black');
    $(this).parent().css('background', '#f60');
});
```

HTML:
    `<ul>
        <li><div class="radioID"><img class="imageRecharge" src="" /></div></li>
        <li><div class="radioID"><img  class="imageRecharge" src="" /></div></li>
    </ul>`

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #000;
}
ul li .radioID {
     padding:5px;   
}

img {
    display: block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [`background-color`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp) CSS property (not `backgroundColor`)

Note that CSS generally uses dash-delimited property names and not camelCase as you tried.

Comment: While this fact is correct, it is not a complete answer AND has already been posted as a comment...

Comment: jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of multiple-word properties, so both are correct

Answer (score 0):

Change div **[background color](https://htmlunderline.com/css-background-color/)** using jQuery

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("button").click(function(){
            $("div").addClass("myclass");
          });
        });
        </script>
        <style>
            .myclass {
              background-color: red;
              padding: 100px;
              color: #fff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
        <button>Click Here</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your profile indicates you're associated with the company that owns the site to which you have linked. Linking to something you're affiliated with (e.g. a product or website) without disclosing it's yours *in your post* is considered spam on Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).